# PrimeNG p-editor Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, quill

My p-editor is not displaying right on site. Please check the image below:
[Top of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfDpx.png)
[Bottom of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzyOn.png)

It is only displaying large SVG and a couple of inputs at the bottom.

I am using Angular v15.2.4, NodeJS v18.15.0, PrimeNG v15.2.1.
I have also installed *quill* via *npm install quill*

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { EditorModule } from 'primeng/editor';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    EditorModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.html

```
<h5>Write Here</h5>
<p-editor [style]="{ height: '120px' }"></p-editor>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have tried updating my Angular and NodeJS to the latest version, but to no avail.
I've tried following tutorial/sample online (official PrimeNG site) and it gave me the same result. Even tried changing from 1 browser to another.

Comment: You're missing Quill CSS: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v14/editor. Only quill.snow.css needs to be added, btw.

PrimeNG most likely messed up their documentation. It should include instructions on how to add Quill resources to your application, just like it did for PrimeNG 14 docs.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added quill.snow.css and it works like a charm! The link that you gave me actually leads to "Page Not Found", letting you know just in case. If anyone is facing the same issue, check your path to "quill.snow.css" then add it to "angular.json" under "styles:[..]". Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

add this line to styles section of angular.json:

```
"node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css"
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you will need to re-serve `ng serve` your project.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have done the installations correctly.

PrimeNG editor uses the Quill package. You should follow this document from Quill docs and https://primeng.org/editor.